# How to distinguish between relocatable and non relocatable symbols inside .data.rel section

Tags: dynamic, linker, arm, relocation

I'm trying to create a simple linker for a barebone ARM application. Currently the loader, that loads the module, will simply add the offset to all records inside the `.got` and `.data.rel` sections. This works fine in `.got`, and for all symbols that need relocation inside `.data.rel`. It will break though for all non-relocatable data, as those will get this offset too.

Example:

```
void some_function() { return; }

struct a {
    void* fptr;
    int number;
};

static struct a = {
   .fptr = some_function,
   .number = 0x1000,
};
```

Here `a.fptr` will correctly address the actual location of the function, but `a.number` will incorrectly hold `0x1000 + offset`, instead of just `0x1000`.

How should I distinguish between the two? Is it enough that I check the `.symtab` section and only relocate addresses that are found there? But what if a symbol is actually at location `0x1000`? Or does the linker address this issue (so it will not put a function at address `0x1000`)? Does `.symtabs` actuall contain all symbols that can be found inside `.got` and `.data.rel`?

Comment: I wrote a basic ELF loader a while ago and I recall that you only add offsets to relocation entries marked as "R_ARM_ABS32". You can find the code here https://github.com/tangrs/ndless-elfloader/blob/master/elf/elf_load.c

Comment: and how to add relocation entries to the elf file? readelf says it's not there, but I use -r -fpic to compile/link. (btw. you should add this as an answer so I can upvote it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a basic ELF loader a while ago and I recall that you only add offsets to relocation entries marked as "R_ARM_ABS32".

You can find the code here https://github.com/tangrs/ndless-elfloader/blob/master/elf/elf_load.c

I simply linked my ELF files with --emit-relocs turned on. That way, the linker does all the linking, it just tells me what it did so you can fix up offsets during load time.

Comment: The actual problem was that I used gcc, so i had to use "-Xlinker --emit-relocs" in the command line. With relocs enabled the task became easy.